# Escribir sentencias preparadas en menos líneas

Tags: php, mysql

¿Hay alguna forma de escribir estas instrucciones SQL en menos líneas?

```
$sentence_1 = $conn->prepare("DELETE FROM us_sub WHERE user_id_fk=?");
$sentence_1->bind_param("i", $id);
$sentence_1->execute();

$sentence_2 = $conn->prepare("DELETE FROM users WHERE id=?");
$sentence_2->bind_param("i", $id);
$sentence_2->execute();
```

Lo que hace es eliminar un usuario de la tabla '`users`' pero como tiene foreign key, debe eliminarse antes de '`us_sub`'.

Me gustaría saber si es posible realizar estas instrucciones en menos líneas sin utilizar **ON DELETE CASCADE** pero si está bien como lo tengo lo puedo dejar así.

Sin embargo, puede haber algún riesgo de seguridad con estas instrucciones?

Answer (score 0):

también puedes ejecutar varias sentencias a la vez.

```
$sentence_1 = $conn->prepare("
     DELETE FROM us_sub WHERE user_id_fk=?;
     DELETE FROM users WHERE id=?;");
$sentence_1->bind_param("i", $id);
$sentence_1->execute();
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, acabo de probar el código y me sale el siguiente error: `Uncaught Error: Call to a member function bind_param() `